# Sending an object with Next.js and it is showing up as undefined on the page I am sending it to

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, frontend, navigation

I am sending an object called `footprintsData` from my question screen to a result screen as shown below:

```
const footprintsData = {
  carFootprint: roundedCarFootprint,
  electricityFootprint: roundedElectricityFootprint,
  gasFootprint: roundedGasFootprint,
  commuteFootprint: roundedCommuteFootprint,
  airTravelFootprint: roundedAirTravelFootprint,
  totalFootprint: parseFloat(totalFootprint.toFixed(2)),
};

router.push({
  pathname: "/results",
  query: { footprintsData: footprintsData },
});
```

At the result screen, I am trying to read the data as follows:

```
const router = useRouter();
const { totalFootprint, carFootprint, electricityFootprint, gasFootprint, commuteFootprint, airTravelFootprint } = router.query;
```

However, it is giving the following error:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'totalFootprint' of 'router.query' as it is undefined.
```

I am using Next.js version 14.1.1 and have tried the following methods to send my data object:

```
console.log("Individual Footprints:", footprintsData);

router.push('/result', query:{carFootprint});

router.push('/test?totalfootprint=' + totalFootprint, { totalFootprint: totalFootprint });

<Link href={{ pathname: "/result", query: footprintsData }}></Link>

<Link href={{ pathname: "/test", query: { totalfootprint: 'totalFootprint' } }}></Link>

<Link href="/result">MOVETORESULTS</Link>
router.push({
   pathname: '/results',
   query: { footprintsData: footprintsData },
});
```

but the same error persists throughout. I even made a test screen with nothing else being displayed but the object was still not being received properly.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have import { useRouter } from "next/router"; ?

If so, maybe try to use 'next/navigation' instead coupled with router.pathname.

Answer (score 0):

Within the [`app`](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/project-structure) router, setting and grabbing query parameters is not done by the [`useRouter`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-router) hook anymore. You should set it yourself:

```
router.push("/results?footprintsData=" + JSON.stringify(footprintsData));
```

And grab it using the [`useSearchParams`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-search-params) hook:

```
import { useSearchParams } from 'next/navigation'
```

```
const searchParams = useSearchParams();
const footprintsData = JSON.parse(searchParams.get("footprintsData"));
console.log(footprintsData);
```